# How does the usage of Gesetz vs. Gesetzgebung differ?

Tags: dictionary

Both of them apparently mean "Law" according to leo dictionary. Could it be explained, then, how their usages differ?

Langenscheidt dictionary gives me an impression that Gesetzgebung maybe like a collection of law.

---

Beide Woerter meinen "Law" laut Leo WoerterBuch. Koennen jemande es erklaeren, wie die Verwendung von diesem zwei Woertern unterscheidet?

Langescheidt Woerterbuch gibt mir das eindruck, dass Gesetzgebung wie eine Menge des Gesetz ist, und Gesetz natuerlich, "Law".

---

Sorry for my bad German.

Comment: die Gesetzgebung — law-making (as a noun)

Comment: Please keep in mind that asking questions in English is absolutely fine and your English text is correctly written, more so than the German (auto-)translation (is "Loewe" supposed to stand for leo.org?).

Comment: You should clarify the substance and content of your question, though. The English lemma "law" is very polysemic ("Parliament passed a new law today", "He broke the law", "She studied law in law school"...), so I'd not recommend to use it as a benchmark for clarity of meaning. What do you expect "Gesetz" to mean, based on the meaning(s) of "law" you have in mind?

Comment: Sometimes, it helps to not only read the first entry in a dictionary - The second and third will give strong hints where the difference lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Gesetz" = an act of a legislature, a law

"Gesetzgebung" = the act of making laws, legislation (as a process)

Ein Gesetz ist das, was bei der Gesetzgebung am Ende herauskommt.